# Dose Spring MVC app in CloudFoundry surpport extending ViewResolver

Tags: spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

When I want to use Rythm template(https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm) in Spring MVC app, and I use the spring-webmvc-rythm-template(https://github.com/lawrence0819/spring-web-rythm-template). 
I publish the app to my own tomcat in eclipse or tc server in STS, it works OK.
But when I publish the app to CF, the extended rythmResolver does not work again, even through I comment the default jsp resolver. 
So I want to know if everyone know that whether CF surpport custom-extended ViewResolver for SpringMVC app?

Comment: It should work the same as your local env. You need to make sure that the introduced libs are all included in the built war file that been deployed to CF.

Comment: Hi William Gu, I have commit my code to github: https://github.com/yeyanzhao/grspsts.git, please help check for the problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: What error/exception do you get? Does the app start? What's in the log? Any stack trace?

Comment: There is no error or exception. And I confirm that the action method already run because the logger.info() statement has been run. But just the ViewResolver deal with this request is the InternalViewResolver but not RythmViewResolver whatever the order of them. It's to say that the RythmViewResolver is whole ignored.

Comment: Ennn....I think I made some error for this question.And this is a pesudo-problem. Just because I use a OS-specific delimiter in one place, cause the file can not be found in the CF server. so the method return false all the time. and this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ennn....I think I made some mistake for this question.And this is a pesudo-problem. Just because I use a OS-specific delimiter in one place, cause the file can not be found in the CF server. so the method return false all the time. and this problem has been solved.